# nivo slider and drop down menu doesnt work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, menu, drop-down-menu, slider

Does anyone has any idea why drop down menu in IE disappear under nivo slider? tried to play with z-index, didn't help, i also know that drop down menus dissappear under flash content, but this is not the case(wmode=transparent) as far as i know the nivo slider uses just jquery, no flash.

here is the html:

```
<table>
<tr height="50"><td colspan="2" align="right" class="bottom_menu">
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal" >
                                             <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.logout" class="dir" style="border:0 !important;" >Çikis</a></li>   
                                             <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.list_basket" class="dir">Sepetim</a></li>
                                             <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.me" class="dir">Sirketim</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.list_opportunities">Firsatlar</a></li>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.form_add_partner">Sirkete Kullanici Ekle</a></li>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.form_upd_my_company">Kullanici Yönetimi</a></li>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.list_analyses">Analizler</a></li>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.list_extre">Hesap Ekstresi</a></li>
                                                 <li><a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.popup_add_online_pos" target="_blank">Sanal Pos</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                             </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>

<div id="banner">
    <img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/l_top.gif" style="z-index:1;position:absolute; left:0; top:0;" width="24px" height="24px" border="0" />
    <img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/r_top.gif" style="z-index:1;position:absolute; right:0; top:0;" width="24px" height="24px" border="0" />
    <img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/l_bottom.gif" style="z-index:1;position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0;" width="24px" height="24px" border="0" />
    <img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/r_bottom.gif" style="z-index:1;position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0;" width="24px" height="24px" border="0" />

    <div class="banner_img">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img title="#1" src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/canon.jpg" alt="" />
        <img title="#2" src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/indigovision.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.detail_product&product_id=612&stock_id=612"><img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/daha_fazlasi.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.detail_product&product_id=630&stock_id=630"><img src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/daha_fazlasi.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'random', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices:15,
        animSpeed:1000, //Slide transition speed
        pauseTime:10000,
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
        controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity:1.0, //Universal caption opacity
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, //Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, //Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} //Triggers when slider has loaded
        });
    });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css for dropdown menu:

http://www.micae.com/documents/templates/projedepo/default.css

http://www.micae.com/documents/templates/projedepo/default.advanced.css

http://www.micae.com/documents/templates/projedepo/dropdown.css

and for nivo slider:

http://www.micae.com/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/style.css

http://www.micae.com/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/nivo-slider.css

and for banner divs:

```
#banner { position:relative; width:980px; height:435px; background:#fff; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:-1px; color:#000; z-index:60; }
.banner_img { padding:8px;position:absolute;z-index:2; }
```

and the javascript by default, jquery and nivo slider

http://www.micae.com/JS/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js

I forgot to mantion, that there is no doctype defined, that's was actually the problem, any ideas how to solve it? i mean without doctype definition. coz when i define the doctype, the design totally crashes...

Comment: You know it would be super useful if you put all that in to jsFiddle.net to give us a proper example ;-)

Comment: ok i will, just a bit later )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE can do some craziness with z-index especially when elements are not positioned.  Make sure the trouble elements, and all their ancestors are positioned relative or absolute explicitly in your css.  It seems like a whole new stacking order is created as soon as there is a break in the chain somewhere.

personally, I always have something like this in my default css:

```
div, ul, li {position:relative;}
```

It seems to solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just make sure that you set all the elements in your dropdown css to have very high z-indexes and explicit positioning ( as in, make sure you state for each one - relative-absolute-etc). For me, the problem only happened in IE, not firefox or chrome, but changing these values (z-index >300+) fixed the problem for me. I hope this helps you, best of luck!